# axios interceptors and eslint

Tags: javascript, axios, eslint

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  config.headers = { ...config.headers, customHeader: 'ABC' };
  return config;
});
```

ESLINT error:

> error  Assignment to property of function parameter 'config'
> no-param-reassign

How to assign my customHeader to config properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  return {
    ...config, 
    headers: {...config.headers, customHeader: 'ABC" }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const newConfig = config;
  newConfig.headers.customHeader= "ABC"
  return newConfig;
});
```